# Is it secure to allow users to create "support tickets" via E-Mail?

Tags: security, email

We are using WHMCS as our support portal which supports the piping of E-Mails into tickets, however, I am wondering if this could become insecure in the event that a forged E-Mail was sent. This is the scenario I am picturing.

User a with E-Mail address "everyoneknowsthis@aol.com" creates an account with us.
Script Kiddie B forges E-Mail headers to send an E-Mail to support@company.com from everyoneknowsthis@aol.com asking for us to install an additional feature on his server or bill him for x, you get the picture.
Would this then not pipe Script Kiddie B's E-Mail into a support ticket were we would have no easy way of identifying if he was actually the client?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, and it's your job to ensure that this isn't a problem, e.g. by requesting confirmation to this known address for anything that could be misused.

Comment: Got it I figured this would be the case.